# Linq "not in"

Tags: c#, linq2sql, entity-framework

Есть список List<USER> users, где USER - сущность.
Как составить запрос типа:

```
from u in context.USER
where !users.Contains(u)
select u;
```

При таких раскладах похоже Linq не понимает выражение !users.Contains(u)

Comment: context.USER.Where(u => !users.Contains(u))
Не понятно, правда, что такое context.USER у Вас (судя по названию, это вообще не коллекция).
Возможно, Вам что-то вроде такого надо:
users.Where(u => u != context.USER)

Comment: context - модель Entity Framework. USER - сущность этой модели. users.Where(u => u != context.USER) - то же самое, только с помощью linq-метода

Comment: А в виде `.Where(u => u != context.USER)` понимает?

Comment: А `users` — это ваша локальная переменная, или поле в Entity? Если локальная переменная, почему просто не `context.User.Except(users)`?

Comment: ругается. Не удалось создать константу с типом "RNTi.App.GUI.Data.USER". В этом контексте поддерживаются только типы-примитивы ("например Int32, String и Guid"). в обоих случаях

Comment: users - это List<USER>, а USER - сущность entity. С Except та же фигня.

Comment: А какая именно ошибка с Except?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Та же самая. "поддерживаются только типы-примитивы". Тут, думаю, надо либо переопределять оператор == или реализовывать IEqualityComparer. Сделал сравнение по полю примерно так

```
var users_for_replace = from u in context.USER
                        where !users.Contains(u.U_ID)
                        select u;
```

Теперь users - List<int>